# Error in reading uint32_t variable saved in a file

Tags: c, uint32

I have an issue with writing a `uint32_t` value to a file and reading it back.
For writing it into a file, I use

```
uint32_t num = 2036465665 ; 
FILE *fp = fopen("test.dat", "w");
fprintf(fp,"value = %" PRIu32 "\n", num);
fclose(fp);
```

For reading it, I first copy the contents of file into an array `data[]` and then extract values line by line.

```
int len = 100;
char *line = malloc(len * sizeof(char));
char field[256], tmp[2];

FILE *fp = fopen("test.dat", "r");
while ( -1 != getline(&line, &len, fp)){
            char *value=malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
            sscanf( line, "%s %s %s", field, tmp, value);
            data[i] = value;
            i++;
        }
 fclose(fp);
```

To read the value of uint32_t variable, I get different values with `atoi` and `strtoul` with different bases, but not the exact value written into the file.

```
uint32_t read_num;
read_num = strtoul (data[0], NULL, 32);
```

This gives value of read_num as 1345324165.

```
read_num = (uint32_t) atoi(data[0]);
```

gives 3226523632

How do I get the correct value saved in the file. Is the error in (i) reading the file contents using `sscanf` into string or (ii) the `strtoul` vs `atoi` (iii) base in `strtoul()`.

Comment: strtoul (data[0], NULL, 32); -- Are your values in base 32? I would look up how to use this function properly; based on what I have glanced at it should be 10, not 32.

Comment: Also I would recommend using EOF rather than -1 as the return check for getline.

Comment: @MateoConLechuga: Actually, [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) is defined in POSIX to return `-1` and not `EOF`, so using `-1` is correct.

Comment: Oops I forgot; thank you

Comment: @MateoConLechuga: base 10 doesn't work either.

Comment: @kris: have you printed out the string that you do read?  What is the definion of the `data` array? Did you check the return value from `sscanf()`?

Comment: Is your test.dat file ascii? Please post a sample of it if possible.

Comment: Add width limits and check return value `if (3 != sscanf( line, "%255s %1s %255s", field, tmp, value) puts("oops");`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, yes when I read the string as printf("%s %s %s\n", field, tmp, value); it prints out value = 3226523632.

Comment: @chux, I've tested with the return value, it doesn't print 'oops'.

Comment: My compiler complained about `int len;` not being a good match for the `size_t *` that `getline()` expects.  Is that a factor in your problem?  With that fixed (I tell the compiler to treat warnings like errors), I got your code to work for me (macOS Sierra 10.12.4, GCC 6.3.0 — 64-bit compilation).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I've changed  `int len` to  `size_t len`. Mine is  64-bit Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49). It doesn't work for me yet.

Comment: Gosh! That's an old XCode release; I have 8.1.0 clang-802.0.41.  However, I don't think the compiler version is an issue here.   Try the code from my "it doesn't reproduce" answer (it was too big to try placing it as a string of comments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adapted your code fragments into this close-to-MCVE ([Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), and it seems to work correctly on my Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.4 using GCC 6.3.0 as the compiler.  (I also get the same results with `clang` — Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.41).)

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void write_data(const char *filename)
{
    uint32_t num = 2036465665; 
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "w");
    assert(fp != NULL);
    fprintf(fp,"value = %" PRIu32 "\n", num);
    printf("Wrote %" PRIu32 "\n", num);
    fclose(fp);
}

int main(void)
{
    const char filename[] = "test.dat";

    write_data(filename);

    char *data[10];
    size_t len = 100;
    char *line = malloc(len * sizeof(char));
    assert(line != 0);
    char field[256], tmp[2];

    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    assert(fp != NULL);
    int i = 0;
    while ( -1 != getline(&line, &len, fp))
    {
        printf("Read: [%s]\n", line);
        char *value = malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
        assert(value != 0);
        if (sscanf(line, "%s %1s %s", field, tmp, value) != 3)
            assert(0);
        printf("Field [%s] tmp [%s] value [%s]\n", field, tmp, value);
        data[i] = value;
        i++;
    }
    free(line);
    fclose(fp);

    char *endptr;
    errno = 0;
    printf("Processing [%s]\n", data[0]);
    uint32_t read_num = strtoul(data[0], &endptr, 10);
    assert(endptr != data[0]);
    free(data[0]);

    printf("Number read: %" PRIu32 "\n", read_num);
    return 0;
}
```

The use of `assert` for error handling is lazy in the extreme, but better than no checking.  The error checking after `strtoul()` is also sloppy — there are unchecked conditions (`read_num == ULONG_MAX` and `errno == ERANGE`, etc.)

When compiled and run, I get:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes \
>     -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition rd53.c -o rd53
$ ./rd53
Wrote 2036465665
Read: [value = 2036465665
]
Field [value] tmp [=] value [2036465665]
Processing [2036465665]
Number read: 2036465665
$
```

If the use of `size_t len` vs `int len` is not your problem, maybe you can try this code and see what it gives you.

Comment: This worked fine for me too. Thank you so much. However, I'm yet to figure out why my sample code did not work !

Comment: Does it have to do with me using NULL in place of `endptr` in your code?

Comment: Now you need to integrate bits from what works into what doesn't.  You are using a version control system, aren't you?

Comment: No; using NULL loses error reporting but doesn't otherwise affect the result.  Add the printing; copious quantities of printing.

Comment: Yes, will check if there is something external that may be affecting my code.